# Resizable widgets while supporting Android 3.0?

Tags: android, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow make an application that supports Android 3.0 while also making it possible for widgets in that application to be resizable if it is run on Android 3.1+.

I'm guessing it's not the case, but I thought I'd check here first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Android 3.1 this is now possible
Add the following to your appwidget-provide element
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"

Example from google

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure"
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical" > </appwidget-provider>
```

I haven't tried, but this code should also work on previousAndroid version (3.0 as well as 2.X and 1.X)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have already tried this and it only works with Android 3.1 and onwards, not 3.0. It's the `android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"` tag that's not supported in 3.0.

Comment: Argh... seem that my answer is totally useless... Sorrry So, your widget does not appear in Android 3.0 or something crash?

Comment: The SDK won't accept the xml if you're targeting Android 3.0 and using the `resizeMode` tag :(

Comment: Ok, is that really a problem for you to upgrade the target (or the SDK) from 3.0 to 3.1? That's just a few clicks, and I guess you won't have a lot of issues..  and you won't loose user due to compatibility issues...

Comment: If I upgrade the target to 3.1, the application cannot be installed on 3.0, can it?

Comment: Yes of course, you can!
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

android:targetSdkVersion
An integer designating the API Level that the application is targetting.
With this attribute set, the application says that it is able to run on older versions (down to minSdkVersion), but was explicitly tested to work with the version specified here. Specifying this target version allows the platform to disable compatibility settings that are not required for the target version (which may otherwise be turned on in order to maintain forward-compatibility)

Comment: You can keep targetSdkVersion low - since if you set it to 11 or above, Android annoyingly kills all your menus because it assumes you understand action bars. Instead, in Eclipse, select Project - Properties - Android - and tick Android 3.1 (or Google APIs 3.1 if you use things like Maps API).